# Can a callback action take different arguments in c#?

Tags: c#, callback, delegates, action

Don't know if it's possible on c# to have a callback that takes diferent arguments.

```cs
public void Woof(){
   Console.WriteLine("woof");
}
public void Woof(System.Action callback){
   Console.WriteLine("woof");
   callback();
}

public void Foo(System.Action callback){
   callback();
   callback(()=> SomeOtherFunction());
}

public void TheCaller(){
   Foo(Woof());
}
```

I know this code won't work, but is there a way to acomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, single delegate can't have varying list of arguments.

Simple solution - make your callback to accept `null`/nullable for arguments that you don't have:

```
 public void Foo(Action<Action> callbackWithOptionalArg)
 {
      callbackWithOptionalArg(null);
      callbackWithOptionalArg(() => SomeOtherFunction());
 }

 Foo( optionalAction => optionalAction == null ? Woof() : Wool(optionalAction));
```

Alternative - have an interface with multiple methods as arguments:

```
interface IWoof
{
   void Woof();
   void Woof(System.Action callback)
}

public void Foo(IWoof dog)
{
  dog.Woof();
  dog.Woof(() => SomeOtherFunction());
}

class MyWoof : IWoof
{
  public void Woof(){
   Console.WriteLine("woof");
  }
  public void Woof(System.Action callback){
    Console.WriteLine("woof with callback");
    callback();
  }
}

Foo(new MyWoof());
```

Comment: Thank you a ton, the first solution is perfect.